# Match letter frequency within a word against 26 letters in R (or python)

Tags: python, r, string

Currently, I have a string `"abdicator"`. I would like find out frequency of letters from this word compared against all English alphabets (i.e., 26 letters), with an output in the form as follows.

Output:

```
a b c d e f g h i ... o ... r s t ... x y z
2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1..0..1..0..1 0 1 ... 0 ...
```

This output can be a numeric vector (with names being the 26 letters). My initial attempt was to first use `strsplit` function to split the string into individual letters (using R):

```
strsplit("abdicator","") #split at every character
#[[1]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"`
```

However, I am a little stuck as to what to do for the next step. Can someone enlighten me on this please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = "abdicator"
>>> Counter(s)
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'i': 1, 'o': 1, 'r': 1, 't': 1})
>>> map(Counter(s).__getitem__, map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)))
[2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Or:

```
>>> import string
>>> map(Counter(s).__getitem__, string.lowercase)
[2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much John. That's exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 9):

In R:

```
table(c(letters, strsplit("abdicator", "")[[1]]))-1
# a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
# 2 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And extending that a bit to handle the possibility of multiple words and/or capital letters:

```
words <- c("abdicator", "Syzygy")
letterCount <- function(X) table(c(letters, strsplit(tolower(X), "")[[1]]))-1
t(sapply(words,  letterCount))
#           a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
# abdicator 2 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
# syzygy    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 1
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, that's a great next step. Just wondering by any chance you would also know how to change this output from table function to include 0 frequency for the letters that did not appear in the word.

Comment: Or `table(factor(strsplit("abdicator", "")[[1]], levels = letters))`

Comment: Hi Josh, this is on the money. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 2):

Python:

```
import collections
import string

counts = collections.Counter('abdicator')
chars = string.ascii_lowercase
print(*chars, sep=' ')
print(*[counts[char] for char in chars], sep=' ')
```

Comment: This code as it stands prints one big unterminated line, and is not using the `string` module it imports.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2:

```
import string, collections
ctr = collections.Counter('abdicator')
for l in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print l,
print
for l in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print ctr[l],
print
```

In Python 3, only the syntax of `print` changes.

This produces exactly the output you requested.  The core idea is that a `collections.Counter`, indexed with a missing key, humbly returns `0` with the obvious semantics "this key has been seen 0 times" fully aligned with the semantics it uses for keys that are present (where it returns their count, i.e, the number of times they have been seen).